# Assign result of sizeof() to ssize_t

Tags: c, posix, sizeof

It happened to me that I needed to compare the result of `sizeof(x)` to a `ssize_t`.

Of course GCC gave an error (lucky me (I used `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`)), and I decided to do a macro to have a signed version of `sizeof()`.

```
#define ssizeof (ssize_t)sizeof
```

And then I can use it like this:

```
for (ssize_t i = 0; i < ssizeof(x); i++)
```

The problem is, do I have any guarantees that `SSIZE_MAX >= SIZE_MAX`? I imagine that sadly this is never going to be true.

Or at least that `sizeof(ssize_t) == sizeof(size_t)`, which would cut half of the values but would still be close enough.

I didn't find any relation between `ssize_t` and `size_t` in the POSIX documentation.

Related question:

[What type should be used to loop through an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55303654/6872717)

Comment: What is the actual problem that require this? This smells like XY-problem.

Comment: The problem is I just want to avoid unsigned types as much as I can, especially in loops, and therefore, I always use `ssize_t` for looping though arrays. But clearly it's a bad design of `ssize_t`. In my case I'm OK, I could just use the same variable I used to create the VLA in the comparison, but it would be better to be able to use `ssize_t`, which purpose is exactly that.

Comment: It's perfectly valid to compare a `size_t` to a `ssize_t`, and though a compiler might *warn* -- about a signed to unsigned comparison, for example -- it ought not to emit an *error*.

Comment: As for preferring `ssize_t` to `size_t`, do note that the former is not defined by standard C.  It is a posixism.  That does not by any means imply that you should avoid it if programming specifically for POSIX, but it is at least something that you should keep in the back of your mind.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't think it's perfectly valid: `for (ssize_t i = 0; i <= SIZE_MAX; i++)` is a good way to test if the infinite exists (in case you don't get a segfault :). I use `ssize_t` in loops to avoid that nasty bug. For the error, yeah I used `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

Comment: I am speaking from a C language perspective.  The comparison of any two values of any arithmetic types is allowed and well-defined, and in that sense valid.  As a quality-of-implementation matter, then, I expect compilers to accept all such comparisons.  I thus find it misleading to claim that GCC rejected such code with an error without (previously) disclosing that you had specifically requested that it treat conditions that normally would elicit only a warning as fatally erroneous.

Comment: Edited the question to mention that :)

Comment: What exactly is the bug that you claim is fixed by using a signed index type and how exactly does the signed type fix the bug? Testing against the largest representable value is a problem for both signed and unsigned types, so I must be misunderstanding something.

Comment: @rici Looping between 0 and the highest positive number (both including) is an infinite loop in unsigned types, but trivial with signed ones (you need to reverse from highest to 0).

Comment: Ok. Of course, you could just use an end-tested loop: `{T i = 0; do { ... } while (i++ < limit); }`. Here, `T` *should* be an unsigned type to avoid overflow in `i++` when `limit` is `T_MAX`. (In practice, integer overflow doesn't trap and the possibly-overflown last value is never used.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no guarantee that `SSIZE_MAX >= SIZE_MAX`. In fact, it is very unlikely to be the case, since `size_t` and `ssize_t` are likely to be corresponding unsigned and signed types, so (on all actual architectures) `SIZE_MAX > SSIZE_MAX`. Casting an unsigned value to a signed type which cannot hold that value is Undefined Behaviour. So technically, your macro is problematic.

In practice, at least on 64-bit platforms, you're unlikely to get into trouble if the value you are converting to `ssize_t` is the size of an object which actually exists. But if the object is theoretical (eg `sizeof(char[3][1ULL<<62])`), you might get an unpleasant surprise.

Note that the only valid negative value of type `ssize_t` is -1, which is an error indication. You might be confusing `ssize_t`, which is defined by Posix, with `ptrdiff_t`, which is defined in standard C since C99. These two types are the same on most platforms, and are usually the signed integer type corresponding to `size_t`, but none of those behaviours is guaranteed by either standard. However, the semantics of the two types are different, and you should be aware of that when you use them:

- `ssize_t` is returned by a number of Posix interfaces in order to allow the function to signal either a number of bytes processed or an error indication; the error indication must be -1. There is no expectation that any possible size will fit into `ssize_t`; the Posix rationale states that:

  > A conforming application would be constrained not to perform I/O in pieces larger than `{SSIZE_MAX}`.

  This is not a problem for most of the interfaces which return `ssize_t` because Posix generally does not require interfaces to guarantee to process all data. For example, both `read` and `write` accept a `size_t` which describes the length of the buffer to be read/written and return an `ssize_t` which describes the number of bytes actually read/written; the implication is that no more than `SSIZE_MAX` bytes will be read/written even if more data were available. However, the Posix rationale also notes that a particular implementation may provide an extension which allows larger blocks to be processed ("a conforming application using extensions would be able to use the full range if the implementation provided an extended range"), the idea being that the implementation could, for example, specify that return values other than -1 were to be interpreted by casting them to `size_t`. Such an extension would not be portable; in practices, most implementations do limit the number of bytes which can be processed in a single call to the number which can be reported in `ssize_t`.
- `ptrdiff_t` is (in standard C) the type of the result of the difference between two pointers. In order for subtraction of pointers to be well defined, the two pointers must refer to the same object, either by pointing into the object or by pointing at the byte immediately following the object. The C committee recognised that if `ptrdiff_t` is the signed equivalent of `size_t`, then it is possible that the difference between two pointers might not be representable, leading to undefined behaviour, but they preferred that to requiring that `ptrdiff_t` be a larger type than `size_t`. You can argue with this decision -- many people have -- but it has been in place since C90 and it seems unlikely that it will change now. (Current standard wording from , §6.5.6/9: "If the result is not representable in an object of that type [`ptrdiff_t`], the behavior is undefined.")

  As with Posix, the C standard does not define undefined behaviour, so it would be a mistake to interpret that as *forbidding* the subtraction of two pointers in very large objects. An implementation is always allowed to define the result of behaviour left undefined by the standard, so that it is completely valid for an implementation to specify that if `P` and `Q` are two pointers to the same object where `P >= Q`, then `(size_t)(P - Q)` is the mathematically correct difference between the pointers even if the subtraction overflows. Of course, code which depends on such an extension won't be fully portable, but if the extension is sufficiently common that might not be a problem.

As a final point, the ambiguity of using -1 both as an error indication (in `ssize_t`) and as a possibly castable result of pointer subtraction (in `ptrdiff_t`) is not likely to be a present in practice provided that `size_t` is as large as a pointer. If `size_t` is as large as a pointer, the only way that the mathematically correct value of `P-Q` could be `(size_t)(-1)` (aka `SIZE_MAX`) is if the object that `P` and `Q` refer to is of size `SIZE_MAX`, which, given the assumption that `size_t` is the same width as a pointer, implies that the object plus the following byte occupy every possible pointer value. That contradicts the requirement that some pointer value (`NULL`) be distinct from any valid address, so we can conclude that the true maximum size of an object must be less than `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: That's a big problem, but the biggest problem is that `ssize_t` could even be smaller than `size_t` because there's nothing in the documentation that says otherwise. I think it's a big bug in POSIX. Read my comments to @Joshua 's answer.

Comment: @cacahuete: the problem is pretty well-known but you're not going to get much traction complaining about it in a SO comment. In practice, the impact of the problem is limited because the only valid negative value fir `ssize_t` is -1. (I'm going to add that observation to my answer when I get back.) `ssize_t` is not guaranteed to be the same as `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: Perfect answer. Yes, I should use `ptrdiff_t`, which is more suited for that task, but still has the same problem of ironically not being able to represent all possible pointer differences. Good to know that at least they considered it, and decided to let it be UB.  Thanks to this question I learnt about it :)

Answer (score 3):

Please note that you can't actually do this.

The largest possible object in x86 Linux is just below 0xB0000000 in size, while `SSIZE_T_MAX` is 0x7FFFFFFF.

I haven't checked if `read` and stuff actually can handle the largest possible objects, but if they can it worked like this:

```
ssize_t result = read(fd, buf, count);
if (result != -1) {
    size_t offset = (size_t) result;
    /* handle success */
} else {
    /* handle failure */
}
```

You may find `libc` is busted. If so, this would work if the kernel is good:

```
ssize_t result = sys_read(fd, buf, count);
if (result >= 0 || result < -256) {
    size_t offset = (size_t) result;
    /* handle success */
} else {
    errno = (int)-result;
    /* handle failure */
}
```

Comment: Then I guess that answers that there's no guarantee of what I asked, but at the same time this proves a bug in POSIX's `ssize_t` and `SSIZE_MAX`, right?  `ssize_t` should be able to hold the size of the largest possible object, or it is useless otherwise.

Comment: And for that reason, IMHO, `(sizeof(ssize_t) > sizeof(size_t)) && (SSIZE_MAX >= SIZE_MAX)` this should be true for that type to make sense.

Comment: On Linux you'll find that you can't read() or write() more than 2147479552 bytes (2 GB - 4k) at a time. But you're using a loop around your read/write anyway to handle short reads and writes and EINTR so it all works out ok.

Comment: And at least on some versions of OSX, trying to read/write more than 2 GB at a time fails outright.

Comment: @janneb: I was wondering if that would be the case. The manual doesn't declare it...

Answer (score 3):

I'm gonna take this on as an X-Y problem.  The issue you have is that you want to compare a signed number to an unsigned number.  Rather than casting the result of `sizeof` to `ssize_t`, You should check if your `ssize_t` value is less than zero.  If it is, then you know it is less than the your `size_t` value.  If not, then you can cast it to `size_t` and then do a comparison.

For an example, here's a compare function that returns `-1` if the signed number is less than the unsigned number, 0 if equal, or 1 if the signed number is greater than the unsigned number:

```
int compare(ssize_t signed_number, size_t unsigned_number) {
    int ret;
    if (signed_number < 0 || (size_t) signed_number < unsigned_number) {
        ret = -1;
    }
    else {
        ret = (size_t) signed_number > unsigned_number;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

If all you wanted was the equivalent of `<` operation, you can go a bit simpler with something like this:

```
(signed_number < 0 || (size_t) signed_number < unsigned_number))
```

That line will give you `1` if `signed_number` is less than `unsigned_number` and it limits the branching overhead.  Just takes an extra `<` operation and a `logical-OR`.

Comment: Yeah, a bit of overhead to do what could be done with a single `<` if the people who designed `ssize_t` weren't braindamaged. :)

Comment: @CacahueteFrito: There is only one negative number in `ssize_t`: -1.

Comment: @Joshua Is it a guarantee by the POSIX standard that `-1` is the only negative number, or `-1` simply the only negative number that is guaranteed to be stored by `ssize_t`?

Comment: @Joshua I knew that, and only need that one to return error, and also avoid infinite loops :)

Comment: @CacahueteFrito I've edited with a drop-in replacement for the `<` operation that should have fairly limited over-head.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons That replacement is ok for checking a return value, but not for a loop condition. That's the same as if I just used `size_t` for the loop counter, which could lead to an infinite loop.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Could you explain what the use-case would be that would lead to an infinite loop?

Comment: Read the related question link I added to the question

Answer (score 3):

ssize_t is a POSIX type, it's not defined as part of the C standard. POSIX defines that ssize_t must be able to handle numbers in the interval [-1, SSIZE_MAX], so in principle it doesn't even need to be a normal signed type. The reason for this slightly weird definition is that the only place ssize_t is used is as the return value for read/write/etc. functions.

In practice it's always a normal signed type of the same size as size_t. But if you want to be really pedantic about your types, you shouldn't use it for other purposes than handling return values for IO syscalls. For a general "pointer-sized" signed integer type C89 defines ptrdiff_t. Which in practice will be the same as ssize_t.

Also, if you look at the [official spec for read()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html), you'll see that for the 'nbyte' argument it says that 'If the value of nbyte is greater than {SSIZE_MAX}, the result is implementation-defined.'. So even if a size_t is capable of representing larger values than SSIZE_MAX, it's implementation-defined behavior to use larger values than that for the IO syscalls (the only places where ssize_t is used, as mentioned). And similar for write() etc.